# Detect special values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to detect values with some specific characters e.g(?,/ etc). Below you can see a small sample with some data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
         'artificial_number':['000100000','000010000','00001000/1','00001000?','0?00/10000'],
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [
                                      'artificial_number',])
```

Now I want to detect values with specific characters that are not numbers `('00001000/1','00001000?','0?00/10000')` I tried with this lines below

```
import re

clean = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\._-]', '', df1['artificial_number'])
```

But this code is not working as I expected. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: you like to remove the non-digit values? can you share the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#replace the non-digit with an empty value
df1['artificial_number'].str.replace(r'([^\d])','', regex=True)
```

```
0    000100000
1    000010000
2    000010001
3     00001000
4     00010000
Name: artificial_number, dtype: object
```

if you like to list the column with non-digit values

```
df1.loc[df1['artificial_number'].str.extract(r'([^\d])')[0].notna()]
```

```
artificial_number
2   00001000/1
3   00001000?
4   0?00/10000
```

Comment: The mask is more logically created with the use of `df1.loc[df1['artificial_number'].str.contains(r'[^\d]', regex=True)]`. Though, as mentioned in my answer, you don't need a regex for this.

Comment: @Naveed I tried but I received this error "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: it worked with your sample dataframe code. you need to add astype(str) prior to the extract, which works on string values

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a *number* in your case is an *integer*, to find the values that have non-numbers, just count the number of numbers, and compare with length of string:

```
rows = [len(re.findall('[0-9]', s)) != len(s) for s in  df1.artificial_number]

df1.loc[rows] 
#  artificial_number
#2        00001000/1
#3         00001000?
#4        0?00/10000
```

Answer (score 1):

To *detect* which of the values aren't interpretable as numeric, you can also use [`str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html):

```
df1.loc[~df1.artificial_number.str.isnumeric()]

  artificial_number
2        00001000/1
3         00001000?
4        0?00/10000
```

If all characters need to be *digits* (e.g. `10.0` should also be excluded), use [`str.isdigit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html#pandas.Series.str.isdigit):

```
df1.loc[~df1.artificial_number.str.isdigit()]

df1.iloc[0,0] = '000100000.0'

  artificial_number
0       000100000.0
2        00001000/1
3         00001000?
4        0?00/10000
```